# Time comparison in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to see if the current time is between 2 times, but I've been having trouble with this one:

This is my code:

```
 If DATE.NOW < CDate(#6:30:00 AM#) And DATE.NOW >= CDate(#10:30:00 PM#) Then
     SHIFT = "NIGHT"
 End If
```

If my time is 11:15 pm I expect to be between the range above, but it doesn't.

More than the formula to get this, i would like to know how the time works in vb.net when you are comparing am vs pm.

Comment: Read your code aloud. How can 11:15 pm (aka 23:15) be both less than 6:30 AndAlso more than 20:30 at the same time?

Comment: @Plutonix The thought, I'm sure, is later than 22:30 and earlier than 06:30 of the next day (since the idea appears to be to capture a night shift).  I can definitely understand the thinking that would lead to it being written the way it is.

Comment: Yeah its from 1 day to another thats wahy i was confused, i used the solution of @visual vincent below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got to change the condition to `OrElse` due to that internally dates are just regular numbers (in this case dates are represented by how many microseconds have lapsed since 0001-01-01). Therefore `Date.Now` cannot possibly be ***both*** less than 6:30 AM ***and*** more or equal to 10:30 PM.

You've also got to add [**`.TimeOfDay`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday(v=vs.110).aspx) to both sides as doing so will compare only the ***time*** of the day, ignoring the date. `#6:30:00 AM#` will evaluate to `0001-01-01 6:30:00 AM`, which is always less than `Date.Now` (`2017-09-25 xx:xx:xx`).

This should work:

```
If Date.Now.TimeOfDay < #6:30:00 AM#.TimeOfDay OrElse Date.Now.TimeOfDay >= #10:30:00 PM#.TimeOfDay Then
```

This checks if the time is less than 6:30 AM, ***or*** more or equal to 10:30 PM.

Comment: @ChristianEA : Glad I could help! I improved the explanation a bit as well. Good luck!